# Why does `super` keyword property returns undefined in an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, class, es6-modules

I'm new to ES6 classes and trying to understand how inheritance works in it. I created a parent class `Modal` and a child class `ChildModal` like this:

```js
class Modal {
    constructor(selector, document) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.document = document;
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }

    set title(title) {
        if(!title) {
            throw new Error('Original title cannot be empty');
        }
        this._title = title;
    }

    defineNewTitle(newContent) {
        this.title = newContent + this.title;
    } 

    assignNewTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var modal = new Modal("#mainTitle");

modal.title = "Standards";

modal.defineNewTitle("JavaScript ");

modal.assignNewTitle();

class ChildModal extends Modal {
    constructor(selector, title) {
        super(selector, title);
    }

    defineChildTitle(title) {
        this.title = title + this.title;
    }

    assignChildTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var child = new ChildModal("#childTitle");
child.defineChildTitle("Wow ");
child.assignChildTitle();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Class test</title>
 <h1 id="mainTitle">
  Main title
 </h1>
 <h2 id="childTitle">
  Child title
</head>
<body>
 <script src="Modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the h2 tag being modified to 'Wow JavaScript Standards', but instead it outputs 'Wow undefined'. Why in method `defineChildTitle` it does not recognise `this.title`? Thought in the `childModal` class, `this.title` should be 'JavaScript Standard`as I've inherited the`Modal`class in the constructor?`enter code here`

Comment: The child inherits from the *class*, not the Modal instance you made. Think about the fact that you could make 20 different Modal instances; which one would drive the inheritance?

Comment: What happens if, instead than `modal.title = "Standards";` you try `modal.prototype.title = "Standards";`?

Comment: in your `ChildModal` constructor, it receives 2 parameters,  isn't that you just pass `#chidTitle` as first para, where's the 2nd one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `_title` in your constructor:

```
class Modal {
    constructor(selector, document) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.document = document;
        this._title = ''
    }
}

var child = new ChildModal("#childTitle");
child.title = "JavaScript Standards"
child.defineChildTitle("Wow ");
child.assignChildTitle();
```

You are currently joining a `string` with `undefined` which results in `undefined`.

Since you are creating two instances, they don't relate to one another, so `child.title` isn't the same as `modal.title`, so concatenating the two will result in two different strings.

So, you not only need to set the title in `modal.title = 'JavaScript Standards'`, but you also must set the same thing to `child.title = 'JavaScript Standards'`.

```js
class Modal {
    constructor(selector, document) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.document = document;
        this.title = ' '
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }

    set title(title) {
        if(!title) {
            throw new Error('Original title cannot be empty');
        }
        this._title = title;
    }

    defineNewTitle(newContent) {
        this.title = newContent + this.title;
    } 

    assignNewTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var modal = new Modal("#mainTitle");

modal.title = "Standards";

modal.defineNewTitle("JavaScript ");

modal.assignNewTitle();

class ChildModal extends Modal {
    constructor(selector, title) {
        super(selector, title);
    }

    defineChildTitle(title) {
        this.title = title + this.title;
    }

    assignChildTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var child = new ChildModal("#childTitle");
child.title = "JavaScript Standards"
child.defineChildTitle("Wow ");
child.assignChildTitle();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Class test</title>
 <h1 id="mainTitle">
  Main title
 </h1>
 <h2 id="childTitle">
  Child title
</head>
<body>
 <script src="Modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set title to the var `child.title` because the two class instances are not related since you used `new` on each one.

Comment: Does that mean I actually don't have to define `_title` in the constructor?

Comment: I updated the constructor to look like this: `this.title = ' '`, You should have it in the constructor, somehow, because having a default of `undefined` probably isn't the best idea here since you know the value will always be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Class fields such as title, selector, and document are not shared between instances. So when you assign a title to your fist `modal` variable, it does not influence any other isntances or classes.

When the ChildModal calls `super(selector, title)`, it passes its title argument to the initialiser of `Modal`. In the `Modal` class, this is then stored in the `document` field.

When you then run `this.title = title + this.title;` the title field does not have a any value. It is `undefined`. Therefore, the title ends up being `"Wow" + undefined`, which results in "Wow undefined".

Comment: Great explanation, I had to read the other answer to understand though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Under the hoods, ES5 classes still use [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

So, another solution could be change `modal.title = "Standards";` to `Modal.prototype.title = "Standards";`.

In this way, you won't change the property in the instance, but you will change the value in the prototype (aka the class definition):

```js
class Modal {
    constructor(selector, document) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.document = document;
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }

    set title(title) {
        if(!title) {
            throw new Error('Original title cannot be empty');
        }
        this._title = title;
    }

    defineNewTitle(newContent) {
        this.title = newContent + this.title;
    } 

    assignNewTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var modal = new Modal("#mainTitle");

Modal.prototype.title = "Standards";

modal.defineNewTitle("JavaScript ");

modal.assignNewTitle();

class ChildModal extends Modal {
    constructor(selector, title) {
        super(selector, title);
    }

    defineChildTitle(title) {
        this.title = title + this.title;
    }

    assignChildTitle() {
        $(this.selector).text(this.title);
    }
}

var child = new ChildModal("#childTitle");
child.defineChildTitle("Wow ");
child.assignChildTitle();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Class test</title>
 <h1 id="mainTitle">
  Main title
 </h1>
 <h2 id="childTitle">
  Child title
</head>
<body>
 <script src="Modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```